# how to insert params to soap api - php soap

Tags: php, soap

I would like to connect with API - send request and get data.

First, I get all the available functions:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://website.com/api.asmx?wsdl');
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

And I display array, like this:

```
[0] => CheckExampleResponse CheckExample(CheckExample $parameters)
```

So, I must use this way:

```
$client->CheckExample($params);
```

but, I don't know how to send this XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="XmlServices">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <xs:GetExample>
            <xs:request>
                <xs:Credentials>
                    <xs:UserName>?</xs:UserName>
                    <xs:Password>?</xs:Password>
                    <xs:PostlId>?</xs:HotelId>
                </xs:Credentials>
                <xs:DataTest>2015-01-01T00:00:00</xs:DataTest>
                <xs:DataTest2>2015-01-02T23:59:59</xs:DataTest2>
                <xs:StatusTest>publish</xs:StatusTest>
            </xs:request>
        </xs:GetExample>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I pass this XML string as an argument to `CheckExample`, I get this error: "Request parameter cannot be null."

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send xml request using soap in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535353/how-to-send-xml-request-using-soap-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetExample method should also appear in the __getFunctions call. Then this should work:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://website.com/api.asmx?wsdl');

$soapmessage = [
    'request' => [
        'Credentials' => [
            'UserName' => '?',
            'Password' => '?',
            'PostlId' => '?'
        ],
        'DataTest' => '2015-01-01T00:00:00',
        'DataTest2' => '2015-01-02T23:59:59',
    ]
];

$result = $client->GetExample($soapmessage);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a SOAP function as a method of `SoapClient`, you are essentially calling the [`SoapClient::__soapCall()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) function, and passing the function name as the first parameter. So, it's good to understand the parameters for this function.

You can see that to pass the arguments, you need to pass an array. This must match what the SOAP server is expecting; the details can be found in the WSDL, and are not displayed by the call to [`SoapClient::__getFunctions()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getfunctions.php). The SOAP service provider should also provide API documentation to determine the proper values, if you don't want to read the WSDL.

It's worth remembering that even if a SOAP function doesn't need any parameters, an empty array must still be passed to the PHP function.